# How to wait a certain time before doing something while running other code?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a project where I'm using the HX711 library with a loadcell to weigh in a fruit that is on a conveyor belt. Each fruit has a weight which needs to be classed. The bigger fruits (200g) are class A so they have to "fall down" the conveyor belt at a later stage. The smaller fruits fall down earlier. This has to be done on a timed basis.

What I want to do is get the fruit size , calculate the class (using weight) and then send an interrupt to the dropping mechanism after x time. But while it must wait to drop the next fruit will be have come in and might be smaller than the first.

I can already weigh in and calculate the class of fruits. I've also done this in C using multithreading but adruino uno doesn't support that.

I also have to mention that there is about 50-200 fruits on a single conveyor belt at any given time.

Comment: Non-blocking code with `millis()` is the answer. Look at the BlinkWithoutDelay example, that comes with the Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp to avoid the blocking code. See [BlinkWithoutDelay](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-led-blink-without-delay) example

Comment: while this is true, it was answer many times. you should search for a duplicate